# import product title + category into Meta Title

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, sql

is there som`e SQL query to import` `Product Title - Category into Meta Title`?

So example: `I have Products and these products have parts.`  I want to i`mport product titles - part titles - categories into Meta Title`.

So if i have: 
product 1 - electric showers
Part 1 -  product 1 -  electric showers

Is there some SQL query to make this?

Comment: please give an good examle

Comment: so here is a product which has parts http://www.theshowerdoctors.ie/mira-sport-7-5-and-8-5-kw-j84.html , i want to add to all parts into meta titles this. MIRA SPORT 7.5 AND 8.5 KW (J84) - MULTI CLAMP BRACKET SPARE - Electric Showers . So first means its product Mira sport 7.5 and 8.5 KW the second is part - MULTI CLAMP BRACKET SPARE and third is category which is Electric Showers

Answer (score 0):

try to do it the "magento-way"

you can obtain products in php with

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

then iterate through the collection and do smth. like

```
$product->setData('meta_keyword',$product->getData('name'));
$product->save();
```

Comment: so what files needs to be changed ?

Comment: can somebody help me more  ?